# Proxy data simultaneously to multiple requests

Tags: node.js, http, http-proxy

I have a server that acts like http proxy. Some GETs take long time (10 seconds or so) to load. In my case sometimes multiple users request the same url approximately at the same time. I want to rewrite that small web-proxy part in nodejs. Currently, simple logic is approximately as follows:

- on each incoming GET start outgoing GET to proxied resource.
- I get progressive updates as proxied resource is downloaded, I write this data in reply to original incoming GET.

I want to update it in such a way so that if there is another concurrent request for the same resource comes in then I'd reuse that first outgoing GET that was already in progress. Basically, progressive updates from the first outgoing GET would be written now to two different incoming GETs.
What can I use in nodejs for that task, is there anything already that does the task? I prefer really simple (I'd rather code it myself, I just don't know what libs I should look into for this task).

Here's sample nodejs code that does that for one connection:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var opt = {host: "static1.example.com", path: req.path};
    var request = http.request(opt, function(response){
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', response.headers['content-length']);
        res.writeHead(response.statusCode);
        response.on('data', function(chunk){
            res.write(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', function(){
            res.end();
            next();
        });
    }).end();
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: @apsillers I just did simple node js for one connection, just update host in opts to direct to some public resource that takes time to load.

Comment: Is it important to simulate the chunking exactly, or could a later connection get "everything we've seen so far" all at once, and then get regular in-progress chunks?

Comment: Also, do you want to generalize this to use multiple (arbitrary) destination resources? (i.e., not just one single `static1.example.com` resource)

Comment: @apsillers no need to reproduce chunking. All at once is good.